# Continuity at $(0,0)$ of $f(x,y)=2xy^2/(x^2+y^4)$ along the paths $φ(t)=(t,t)$ and $ψ(t)=(t^2,t)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb R^2→\mathbb R$, $φ: \mathbb R→\mathbb R^2$, $ψ: \mathbb R→ \mathbb R^2$ be given by $φ(t)=(t,t)$, $ψ(t)=(t^2,t)$, $t ∈ \mathbb R$ and

$$f(x,y) = \begin{matrix} \frac{2xy^2}{x^2+y^4} \quad \text{if $(x,y)$} \neq (0,0) \\ K \qquad \, \, \text{if $(x,y)$} = (0,0)\end{matrix} $$

> Show that $\lim\limits_{t\to0}(f ◦ ψ)(t) = 1$

I will say:

Along the path $ ψ(t)$ where where $x= t^2$ and $y=t$,

$$\lim_{t \to 0} f(ψ(t)) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2t^2\times t^2}{t^4+t^4} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2t^4}{2t^4} = 1 $$

As required.

> Also Show that $\lim\limits_{t\to0}(f ◦ φ)(t) = 0$.

Along the path $ φ(t)$ where $x= t$ and $y=t$,

$$\lim_{t \to 0} f(φ(t)) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2t\times t^2}{t^2+t^4} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2 t^3}{t^2(1+t^2)} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2 t}{(1+t^2)}  = 0 $$

As required.

Am i right and does this show discontinuity along the paths $φ$ and $ψ$ at $(0.0)$?

Comment: You're correct. I don't understand what you mean with discontinuity along the paths $\varphi$ and $\psi$, but what you did proves that there's no $K$ such that $f$ is continuous at the origin.

Comment: Because K does affect/indicate continuity at all?

Comment: Nice proof. Please see the modifications to your question for a proper formatting.